# Java project runs slow from JAR but fast from IDE

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, build

When I run my project from IntelliJ IDE, the GUI is smooth and everything works super fast. When I package it in a JAR, it's very slow.

Edit: Here is a SSCCE demonstrating the problem.

```
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    char[] secret = "Secret password".toCharArray();
    byte[] salt = "Salty salt".getBytes();
    int iterations = 10000;
    int keyLengthBits = 128;
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        long timeStart = System.nanoTime();
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secret, salt, iterations, keyLengthBits);
        SecretKey key = skf.generateSecret(spec);
        long timeEnd = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((timeEnd-timeStart)/1000000 + "ms");
    }
}
}
```

On my machine, running this from IDE prints `25ms` and running from JAR prints `125ms`.

Comment: "Nothing works and nothing is giving out any errors."... then what is the concern here?

Comment: It's very slow.

Comment: just a guess, but maybe your heap size is set to something higher in IDE?

Comment: Profile it (with `jvisualvm` for example) to see what's making it slow.

Comment: I can see from `jvisualvm` that heap size is not a problem. However, `profile` is gray (not clickable). CPU sampling and memory sampling are failing to connect.

Comment: You need to get profiling or sampling to work. There's no logical reason why key derivation would be somehow "boosted" inside an IDE compared to outside of it.

Comment: Do you run it with the same VM parameters and the same JRE? There is no magic in the IDE, it can't make it faster. Try to print from which jar is the class loaded...

Comment: @Meo thank you, that solved it for me. I was running with a different JRE. After forcing the same JRE on both, they began reporting the same speed.